# Stripe Refund on connected account

Tags: php, stripe-payments

i would like to refund a payment on a connected account. Therefore I'm using the following code:

```
$acc = \Stripe\Account::retrieve($conn_account);

$ch_id = "ch_XXXXXXXXXXXXX";

/*$ch = $stripe->charges->capture(
  $ch_id,
  [],
  ['stripe_account' => $conn_account ]
);

echo $ch;
*/

$stripe->refunds->create([
  'charge' => $ch_id,
]);
```

Running the pgp returns
**Fatal error**:  Uncaught (Status 404) (Request req_XXXXXXXX) No such charge: 'ch_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
thrown in **C:\xampp\htdocs\user\vendor\stripe\stripe-php\lib\Exception\ApiErrorException.php** on line **38**<br /

How can I solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you created the charge by setting `Stripe-Account` header to your connected account ID? If so, you need to also set the `Stripe-Account` header when creating your refund. Your code should look like this:

```
$stripe->refunds->create(
  ['charge' => $ch_id ],
  ['stripe_account' => $conn_account ]
);
```

You can take a look at the documentation for more information (like refunding application fees): https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges#issuing-refunds